# (Baby) Rudin exercise 3.12

Tags: real-analysis

Task: Suppose $a_n>0$ and $\sum a_n$ converges. Define $$r_n=\sum_{m=n}^{\infty}a_m.$$

I've shown that $$\frac{a_m}{r_m}+\dots+\frac{a_n}{r_n}>1-\frac{r_n}{r_m}$$ if $m<n$, and $\sum\frac{a_n}{r_n}$ diverges.

Now I need to prove that $$\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{r_n}}<2(\sqrt{r_n} -\sqrt{r_{n+1}})$$ and deduce that $\sum_{a_n}{\sqrt{r_n}}$ converges.

My work so far: (reverse engineering):

I know $$\frac{1}{2}a_n<r_n-r_{n+1}=a_n$$ and $$r_n-\sqrt{r_n}\sqrt{r_{n+1}}<r_n-r_{n+1}=a_n.$$

$$\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{r_n}}(\sqrt{r_n}+\sqrt{r_{n
+1}})<2(\sqrt{r_n} -\sqrt{r_{n+1}})(\sqrt{r_n}+\sqrt{r_{n
+1}})=2a_n$$

$$\frac{1}{2}<\frac{\sqrt{r_n}}{(\sqrt{r_n}+\sqrt{r_{n
+1}})}=1-\frac{\sqrt{r_{n+1}}}{(\sqrt{r_n}+\sqrt{r_{n
+1}})}$$

So it is enough to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{r_{n+1}}}{(\sqrt{r_n}+\sqrt{r_{n
+1}})}=0$ and that's where I'm stuck. I'm not sure if this limit even makes sense since they're actually series. Or how can I show that the denominator is going to infinity? Please let me know if I made some algebra mistake!

Comment: I confess that I have merely skimmed your article.  Perhaps I am mistaken, but isn't the $\lim_{n \to \infty} [r_{(n+1)} - r_n] = 0$?  Assuming so, can't you immediately conclude that the last fraction that you presented will *go to* $(1/2)$?  If this is correct, then, as I see it, there are only two possibilities: either the conjecture that you are trying to prove is false or you have made a mistake in your analysis.  The third possibility is (of course) that my supposition at the start of this comment is inaccurate.

Comment: Correction to supposition at the start of previous comment:  should be $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{r_{(n+1)} - r_n}{r_{(n+1)}} = 0.$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167334/baby-rudin-chapter-3-problem-12?rq=1